# Initial Files List on demand

Tags: fine-uploader

I have 6 fineuploader instances in a single page but different tabs (show/hide divs). I do need to display previous session uploaded files, but my challenge is that if all fineuploader instance starts to display in all tabs, it is going to long time for user to see first tab as each uploader instance will have 50-100 images.

My question....is there any trick in which I can trigger the fineUploader [init files](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/session.html) upon user clicks on the tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Fine Uploader 5.6.0, you can add initial files to the library at any time with [the `addInitialFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addInitialFiles). So when your user clicks on the tab, you can retrieve your initial files list from the server (or wherever it exists) and then pass this data to `addInitialFiles`.

Comment: That is very interesting solution and glad that I have asked. FU is really sophisticated uploader; I dis not not see any example of anyone using this feature,and will try to explore this in few days. Thanks Ray.

Comment: Any luck using this new API method? I don't see a reason why it wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: Not yet Ray. It is my list of TODO; I will update this thread when have some results/update.

Comment: @Ray..Finally, I am getting into this priority. Now, FU in most case uses endpoint: to retrieve the files from sever or s3, and that is the only approach that am aware. 'addInitialFiles' does not have 'endpoint:' and how would I pass list files from php to java script? do you have any sample code using FU?

Comment: @bizready http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addInitialFiles

Comment: Ray..thanks  it all worked smoothly. I used ajax call to get the data from server and then load that to uploader.

Comment: @bizready Glad to hear it. Can you please go through and mark any answers that helped you in your questions as accepted? This will make it easier for other users to find solutions, and also possible for me to mark similar questions as duplicates.